# slabtext.js - text overflowing container

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-face

Using slabtext.js to reformat headings on a page, but am finding the processed text is spilling outside its container. If I do a hard refresh of the page it's fine, but just hitting f5 leaves me with overflowing text, which messes with my layout.

The slabtext span elements are constrained to the width of their parent, but the rendered text overflows.

I'm using @font-face for the styled text - is it possible this is causing the issue? If the text is styled after slabtext runs, it would end up as a different width causing the spill - not sure why that would happen though as the slabtexting is one of the final functions I run.

Any ideas?

Comment: even though your function is one of the last one's loaded, the font-face could be taking longer to load, disable font-face and see if you get same issue with header, if you do you need to look for a way to add the slabtext after the font has rendered

Comment: Yeah, sorted this a few minutes after posting it - I was initialising the javascript on DOMready, have move it to window load instead and all is well - seems CSS references to fonts do not result in the font downloading, hence my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem as well and your comment helped me out. Just posting the anwser for a bit more clarity.

Coffeescript:

```
$( window ).load ->
  $("#introduction h2").slabText viewportBreakpoint: 0
  return
```

jQuery:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  $("#introduction h2").slabText viewportBreakpoint: 0
});
```